# Infinite matrices and counting arguments on the number rows and columns it MUST have?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I have a matrix say $D$ and I know that $D$ has an infinite number of entries.  Are at least one of the following statements true

***(1)*** D has infinitely many columns and infinitely many rows

***(2)*** D has at least one infinite column

***(3)*** D has at least one infinite row.

Infinite here means the same cardinality as the integers. I am certain that $D$ cannot have a finite number of rows and finite number of columns otherwise you cannot assign infinitely many entries to $D$.

Comment: One of (2) and (3) must be true, but they need not be true simultaneously.  Of course, if (1) is true, then both (2) and (3) are true.  Note that we can have a matrix with finitely many rows and infinitely many columns or vice versa.

Comment: Straightforward and I thought so. I want to make sure I understood this clearly.

Comment: What does an "infinite column", respectively an "infinite row" mean here? That the column/row has infinitely many nonzero elements? If so, a matrix in $\mathbb R^{\omega\times\omega}$ with ones on the diagonal and zeroes everywhere else will have infinitely many nonzero entries, but no infinite columns or rows ...

Comment: Good follow up question. Every entry in D is a non zero integer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think your matrix has cardinality greater than the Integers?